# I can't reuse returned variable from php

Tags: jquery

I want to call a php file and return variable then i want to initialize a variable in jquery to the php result.
then at last i want to resend the same variable to a php file but i returns null this time and php considers the variable as undefined.

this is my code:

```
var cityid;

$.post('test1.php', 
{
  username: cuser
}, 
function(data){
  cityid = data;
});
```

Now i can use cityid in jquery its all fine but if i want to send it to php again or assign new variable then send it to php it returns nothing and when i check the variable type in php it says "**string(9) "undefined** and the variable is undefined! here is the new php call:

```
$.post('test1.php', 
   {
       cid: cityid
    }, 
    function(data){
       alert(data);
       $(".card3").html(data);
    });
```

I'm getting the variable as post `$cityid = $_POST['cid'];`

Comment: `undefined` would imply that `cityid` is undefined in your javascript.

Comment: PHP isn't saying it is undefined. That is the actual value that the JS is sending because JS has it undefined. Check your developer console.

Comment: please show the full code. Because the second call has to be _inside_ the callback of the first one.

Comment: Yeah you were right it is undefined in JS i just figured that out, i was alerting it inside the function it gives data but from outside the function it is undefined

Comment: that was the full code in jquery

Comment: read about asynchronous functions to understand why!

Comment: Thank you all for your time, the second fuction should be in the first one.

Comment: But is there any other way to use the variable outside the function?

Comment: Not really. You can call another (outside) function from 'inside' with the var as parameter.

Comment: Oh okay i got it Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function should be inside the first function to be able to use the value of the variable